# How can I open the url that input by the user

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driverPath = "C:/Users/陳子雋/Desktop/Coding Projects/爬蟲/chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(driverPath)
url = input()
browser.get(url)
```

How can I open an url that input by user?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you get the user input first and then initialize the webdriver like this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = input()
driverPath = "C:/Users/陳子雋/Desktop/Coding Projects/爬蟲/chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(driverPath)
browser.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by first running the command `pip install webbrowser` and then the following code:

```py
import webbrowser
url = input("Enter the URL")
webbrowser.open(url)
```